# useEffect() in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I would like to understand why I can't put state variable in the useEffect alert.

If I put state variable then I see `i am clicked [object Object]` in the alert box.

```js
const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    alert("i am clicked " + {num});
  }, []);
```

Comment: You are not ' alerting ' the num state value but an object  {num}. Just use `"i am clicked" + num` or ` i am clicked ${num}` . This has nothing to do with react. But with javascript basics. Also, when coming across such ' strange  ' behavior , try some basic debugging ( trial and error )  like removing the braces, see what happens.

Comment: You can put it in the alert. For some reason (are you confusing it with a template string?) you surround it with braces, making it an object.

Comment: thank you yes i missed dollar sign. i tried with template strings but i did not put dollar sign. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have put `{num}`. Instead use `num` without the braces `{}` like

```
const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  alert("i am clicked " + num);
}, []);
```

That's why it's alerting `[Object object]`. You'd be better off using `console.log`.

To learn about `useEffect`, check out [React docs on it](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: i did the same except i put curly braces around num. this is I was missing. Thank you  so much for this learning

Comment: @NishantSethi u can accept the answer now by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using template strings like so.

```
const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    alert(`i am clicked ${num}`);
  }, []);
```